# ArcGIS ModelBuilder and Inline Variable Substitution Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-999999

I have a feature class consisting of about 100 or so lines. I'm trying to use ModelBuilder to generate a profile table for each line so that I can generate elevation profiles for each one. My model is below.

[image]

I want each profile table to have the same name as the Name variable so the path ends with %Name%. Whenever I try to run the model like this, it returns Error 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds. I would rather not contact ESRI support.

I've come to the conclusion that the inline variable substitution is what's causing the problem as when I run the model giving Profile Table a fixed name at the end of the path, it runs to completion and one profile table is present in the destination folder. It's the profile table for the last feature that gets iterated. I'm not very experienced with ModelBuilder so it may be something obvious that I'm missing.

Does anybody have any idea what the root of this issue may be?

Comment: What is the value in Profile Table? Have you set your environment cellsize, output coordinate system, snap raster, output extent?

Comment: The value of profile table is C:\Users\Jake\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages\MBW_Maps_Package_8e7984\commondata\profile_tables\%Name%.

Comment: Cell size, output coordinate system, snap raster, and extent are all set equal to the DEM.

Comment: Is profile table an info table or have you specified the extension .dbf in the Name variable? A table name with no extension is written as an info table in an ArcINFO workspace, if you folder contains a corrupt workspace you will experience issues similar to what you are describing.

Comment: Specifying the .dbf extension in the name of profile table solved the problem.

Comment: That's great Jake, now can you answer your own question for the benefit of future users with a similar problem.